# Create Vertical Violin Plot in Vega

Tags: json, charts, visualization, vega-lite, vega

i am desperately trying to switch the axis on this Vega Lite violin plot example, but i can not figure it out. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A violin plot example showing distributions for pengiun body mass.",
  "width": 500,
  "padding": 5,

  "config": {
    "axisBand": {
      "bandPosition": 1,
      "tickExtra": true,
      "tickOffset": 0
    }
  },

  "signals": [
    { "name": "plotWidth", "value": 60 },
    { "name": "height", "update": "(plotWidth + 10) * 3"},
    { "name": "trim", "value": true,
      "bind": {"input": "checkbox"} },
    { "name": "bandwidth", "value": 0,
      "bind": {"input": "range", "min": 0, "max": 200, "step": 1} }
  ],

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "penguins",
      "url": "data/penguins.json",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.Species != null && datum['Body Mass (g)'] != null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "density",
      "source": "penguins",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "kde",
          "field": "Body Mass (g)",
          "groupby": ["Species"],
          "bandwidth": {"signal": "bandwidth"},
          "extent": {"signal": "trim ? null : [2000, 6500]"}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "stats",
      "source": "penguins",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["Species"],
          "fields": ["Body Mass (g)", "Body Mass (g)", "Body Mass (g)"],
          "ops": ["q1", "median", "q3"],
          "as": ["q1", "median", "q3"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "layout",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "height",
      "domain": {"data": "penguins", "field": "Species"}
    },
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "width", "round": true,
      "domain": {"data": "penguins", "field": "Body Mass (g)"},
      "domainMin": 2000,
      "zero": false, "nice": true
    },
    {
      "name": "hscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": [0, {"signal": "plotWidth"}],
      "domain": {"data": "density", "field": "density"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "penguins", "field": "Species"},
      "range": "category"
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale", "zindex": 1},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "layout", "tickCount": 5, "zindex": 1}
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {
          "data": "density",
          "name": "violin",
          "groupby": "Species"
        }
      },

      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "yc": {"scale": "layout", "field": "Species", "band": 0.5},
          "height": {"signal": "plotWidth"},
          "width": {"signal": "width"}
        }
      },

      "data": [
        {
          "name": "summary",
          "source": "stats",
          "transform": [
            {
              "type": "filter",
              "expr": "datum.Species === parent.Species"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],

      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "area",
          "from": {"data": "violin"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": {"parent": "Species"}}
            },
            "update": {
              "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "value"},
              "yc": {"signal": "plotWidth / 2"},
              "height": {"scale": "hscale", "field": "density"}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "rect",
          "from": {"data": "summary"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "fill": {"value": "black"},
              "height": {"value": 2}
            },
            "update": {
              "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "q1"},
              "x2": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "q3"},
              "yc": {"signal": "plotWidth / 2"}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "rect",
          "from": {"data": "summary"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "fill": {"value": "black"},
              "width": {"value": 2},
              "height": {"value": 8}
            },
            "update": {
              "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "median"},
              "yc": {"signal": "plotWidth / 2"}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I already tried switching the axis by swapping xcale and hscale but that always resulted in the violins not showing up or in an empty canvas in general. Can i maybe find a comprehensive guide to defining and managing axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A violin plot example showing distributions for pengiun body mass.",
  "width": 400,
  "padding": 5,
  "config": {
    "axisBand": {"bandPosition": 1, "tickExtra": true, "tickOffset": 0}
  },
  "signals": [
    {"name": "plotWidth", "value": 60},
    {"name": "height", "update": "(plotWidth + 10) * 6"}
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "penguins",
      "url": "data/penguins.json",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum.Species != null && datum['Body Mass (g)'] != null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "density",
      "source": "penguins",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "kde",
          "field": "Body Mass (g)",
          "groupby": ["Species"],
          "extent": {"signal": "[2000, 6500]"}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "stats",
      "source": "penguins",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["Species"],
          "fields": ["Body Mass (g)", "Body Mass (g)", "Body Mass (g)"],
          "ops": ["q1", "median", "q3"],
          "as": ["q1", "median", "q3"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "layout",
      "type": "band",
      "range": "width",
      "domain": {"data": "penguins", "field": "Species"}
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "round": true,
      "domain": {"data": "penguins", "field": "Body Mass (g)"},
      "domainMin": 2000,
      "zero": false,
      "nice": true
    },
    {
      "name": "hscale",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": [0, {"signal": "plotWidth"}],
      "domain": {"data": "density", "field": "density"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "domain": {"data": "penguins", "field": "Species"},
      "range": "category"
    }
  ],
  "axes": [
    {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "layout", "zindex": 1},
    {"orient": "left", "scale": "yscale", "tickCount": 5, "zindex": 1}
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {
        "facet": {"data": "density", "name": "violin", "groupby": "Species"}
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "xc": {"scale": "layout", "field": "Species", "band": 0.5},
          "width": {"signal": "plotWidth"},
          "height": {"signal": "width"}
        }
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "summary",
          "source": "stats",
          "transform": [
            {"type": "filter", "expr": "datum.Species === parent.Species"}
          ]
        }
      ],
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "area",
          "from": {"data": "violin"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": {"parent": "Species"}},
              "orient": {"value": "horizontal"}
            },
            "update": {
              "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "value"},
              "xc": {"signal": "plotWidth / 2"},
              "width": {"scale": "hscale", "field": "density"}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "rect",
          "from": {"data": "summary"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {"fill": {"value": "black"}, "width": {"value": 2}},
            "update": {
              "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "q1"},
              "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "q3"},
              "xc": {"signal": "plotWidth / 2"}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "rect",
          "from": {"data": "summary"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "fill": {"value": "black"},
              "height": {"value": 2},
              "width": {"value": 8}
            },
            "update": {
              "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "median"},
              "xc": {"signal": "plotWidth / 2"}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```